# R: boxplot with minutes and seconds in y axis

Tags: r, datetime, boxplot

When I `boxplot` some data measured in seconds in R, how can I change the scale of the y axis from seconds to minutes and seconds?

For example when I do something like this:

```
data <- c(298, 507, 1008, 346)
boxplot(data)
```

I get a `boxplot` with an y axis from 300 to 1000. I would like to have "5:00" to "16:40" there instead, simply the seconds converted to minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an attempt. It turns the y axis off first and then converts the data to minutes and adds it to the y-axis as tickmarks.

```
data <- c(298, 507, 1008, 346)
boxplot(data, yaxt="n")
at <- axTicks(2)
axis(2, at=at, labels=sprintf("%d:%02d", at %/% 60, at %% 60), las=1)
```

To provide a little explanation:

`axTicks` "*Computes pretty tickmark locations, the same way as R does internally.*" (from `?axTicks`).

`%%` will give you the remainder after division, while `%/%` will, if given `x %/% y` tell you how many times `x` goes into `y`.

Finally, `sprintf` is used for formatting strings and will pad the calculated seconds value to always append leading `0`'s if required, i.e. - `2` becomes `02`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative with function `axis.POSIXct`:

```
data <- c(298, 507, 1008, 346)
data2 <- as.POSIXct(data, origin=cut(Sys.time(), "hours"))
boxplot(data2, pars=list(yaxt="n"))
axis.POSIXct(2, at=pretty(data2), format="%M:%S", las=2)
```

[image]